# Javascript: Adding timeout to synchronous REST API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I'm going to call a function which makes a Synchronous REST API call. I want to somehow timeout on that function call if it does not return within some time. How do I do that?

```
callBlahService = function(args){
    // make actual rest api call
    $.ajax{
        // arguments
        async: false
    }
}

callBlahService({
    success:function(data){
        console.log("blah successful");
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("blah failed");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using JQuery. There is a `timeout` setting on `$.ajax` that should be use: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Your error handler will get called if the timeout is exceeded.

```
$.ajax({
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(response) {},
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("timed out!");
        } 
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

> **timeout**
>
> Type: [Number](http://api.jquery.com/Types#Number)
>
> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. **In jQuery 1.4.x and below**, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. **In Firefox 3.0+ only**, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.
> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Also what happens after the timeout on REST request? does it call error method?